# MS Access ComboBox Storing the Wrong Bound Column Value

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, combobox

I have a ComboBox object in an Access form that pulls its data from a query. The Query returns 2 columns. For example, the columns are **"Section"** and **"Title"**. "Title" is the value I would like stored and displayed in the ComboBox once selected, but "Section" is the value that displays, regardless of the Bound Column value I set.

Both columns are necessary information in the drop-down list (for user context), but only "Title" is required by the Access Form, as it is the primary key in its own table, and "Section" is not a unique value from which "Title" can be logically derived.

The display order of the columns in the dropdown is **"Section | Title"** and shall remain so, since it will read **"1.1.2.1 | Introduction to History"** in the list which is more legible than the inverse.

As mentioned, I've tried setting the Bound Column value to 0, 1, 2, and 3, knowing that there are only 2 columns to choose from and that Bound Column starts at an index of 1.

- **Bound Column: 0** - Returns Blank (Out of Range)
- **Bound Column: 1** - Returns Column 1 ("Section")
- **Bound Column: 2** - Returns Column 1 ("Section")
- **Bound Column: 3** - Returns Blank (Out of Range)

Both columns display on the dropdown list, but any reasonable change to the Bound Column property does not stop the ComboBox from displaying the first column from the selected row every time. Having the query return an extra third row and setting the Bound Column to 3 also does not change the outcome -- "Section" is still the displayed value.

Comment: What is ColumnWidths property set to? If you want user to see Section in dropdown but view Title in box, make sure Section is second field in SQL. Having a descriptor like a Title is rather odd. Why are you not using autonumber field as key?

Comment: ColumnWidths: 1";3"... and I'd like to keep the column order in the dropdown view as "Section | Title". Changing the order of the columns in the query will change the column order in the dropdown and I'd like to avoid that if possible. Will a ComboBox always default to the first column displayed in the dropdown, regardless of the Bound Column?

Comment: Yes, first column not set to 0 width displays in box. This is also what user must type to match listed item.

Comment: Dangit... that's not what I was hoping to hear, but you're right. Setting "Title" to the leftmost visible column does fix my issue. I don't like the visuals, but I guess it can't be helped :( Thanks for pointing that out!